# MySQL: Sum on a Large Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

`mail_info` with columns `CustomerID, MailID, Opened`

`mail_ids` with columns `MailID, MailType, SendDate`

`mail_data` with columns `CustomerID, Item, Sales, PurchaseDate`

I want to sum the `Sales` for each `CustomerID`, grouped by each `PurchaseDate`, and also display the binary `Opened` data for each customer/date pair.

The derived `basetable` is to relate each `MailID` to its corresponding date for use in `mail_data`.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT CustomerID, Opened, SendDate, SUM(mail_data.Sales) FROM
(SELECT 
    mail_info.CustomerID,
    mail_info.Opened,
    mail_ids.SendDate
    FROM mail_info
    INNER JOIN mail_ids ON mail_info.MailID = mail_ids.MailID
    WHERE mail_ids.MailType = 'E'
) AS basetable
INNER JOIN mail_data ON mail_data.PurchaseDate = basetable.SendDate
GROUP BY CustomerID, SendDate
ORDER BY CustomerID, SendDate ASC;
```

And desired output example:

```
# CustomerID, Opened, SendDate, SUM
1, 1, 2017-01-03, 5.68
1, 0, 2017-01-04, 4.92
1, 0, 2017-01-05, 43.23
2, 1, 2017-01-03, 12.65
2, 1, 2017-01-04, 283.24
2, 0, 2017-01-05, 74.23
```

I can run the basetable `SELECT` instantly, however when I add the `SUM` function and `INNER JOIN mail_data` to the derived table, the query runs until server timeout (many hours).

The `mail_data` table is about 600 million rows, the other tables are relatively tiny.

I added an index on `mail_data.PurchaseDate`, and `EXPLAIN` suggests that the index is being used in the query. I have also increased buffer sizes and moved the data to an SSD.

Could this be an issue with server or database optimization, or is my query simply written incorrectly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, it is best not to use subqueries (derived tables) unless you need to.  They tend to be materialized -- saved on disk as temporary tables -- and that can impede performance.

So, try this:

```
SELECT minf.CustomerID, minf.Opened, mi.SendDate, SUM(md.Sales)
FROM mail_info minf INNER JOIN
     mail_ids mi
     ON minf.MailID = mi.MailID INNER JOIN
     mail_data md
     ON md.PurchaseDate = mi.SendDate and
        md.CustomerID = mi.CustomerID
WHERE mi.MailType = 'E'
GROUP BY minf.CustomerID, mi.SendDate
ORDER BY minf.CustomerID, mi.SendDate ASC;
```

I added an additional `JOIN` condition on `CustomerID`.  This seems reasonable.

Your table is processing a lot of rows.  You may think the `basetable` query is returning quickly -- but it may only be returning the first rows in the result set.  The `GROUP BY` requires reading *all* the data and then doing more processing, so it will take longer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, the query still ran through the night and hasn't stopped yet. Is there more I can do to optimize the query? I feel it shouldn't take so long on an SSD, and CPU usage is only at 13%.

Comment: @GraysonWyker . . . I added a `JOIN` condition the lack of which might explain the performance issue.